# Вложенный div в другой div. Смещаются background-image.

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. Такая проблема по верстке. Есть два вложенных дива, у каждого из них есть фоновая картинка background-image. Почему то фоновая картинка родительского дива смещается под фоновую картинку вложенного.

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю, вы хотите общий фоновый градиент по всей ширине у wraaper-header и поверх него отцентрированную карту?

У вас во-первых слишком маленькая (в высоту) фоновая картинка для градиента: 59px. Во-вторых вы говорите ей отображаться по низу блока wrapper-header:
background: url("") repeat-x left **bottom** transparent;

Вырезайте высокую градиент-картинку для фона (размером с высоту wrapper-header). И в принципе, позиционирование по низу можно будет оставить.

Так же обратите внимание на [CSS3-градиенты](http://htmlbook.ru/css3-na-primerakh/lineinyi-gradient).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Да, не заметила, что высота картинки первого дива маленькая, сохранила не правильно.